# C# mocking Mock<StreamWriter>

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I am new to C# mocking, I am trying to read some code and I got one of the tests failing, can you please explain to me what the below source code is trying to test and when will it fail?

```
Mock<StreamWriter> _streamWriterMock;
string[] expectedLines;
.
.
.
foreach (var line in expectedLines)
{
    _streamWriterMock.Verify(a => a.Write(line), Times.Exactly(1));
}
```

Comment: This is not a [mcve]. The omitted code makes it difficult to tell what it being tested as well the omission of the subject under test. At best the `foreach` is verifying with the mock that the expected lines were called on the stream writer's `Write` method.

Comment: What mocking framework are you using?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Verify**
*You might want to check that the method under test was called, or even how many times that method was called*

Just to  reproduce the issue  try this code

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var _streamWriterMock = new Mock<StreamWriter>("output.txt");
        string[] expectedLines= new []{"test","test"};

        foreach (var expectedLine in expectedLines)
        {
            _streamWriterMock.Object.Write(expectedLine);
        }
        foreach (var line in expectedLines)
        {
           _streamWriterMock.Verify(a=>a.Write(line),Times.Exactly(1));    
        }

    }
}
```

In fact, if you try to mock your code with the array `{"test","test"}` you will  get an exception
  `Expected invocation on the mock exactly 1 times, but was 2 times: a => a.Write("test")`

But if your array is something like the following

`string[] expectedLines= new []{"test","test1"};`

Your mock will be executed correctly

So your `verify` will check if your method is called exactly once for the same input.
I think that the code main goal is to omit that you write the same output twice.

Answer (score 0):

The test in your example iterates through all of the strings in your expectedLines array and checks that _streamWriterMock.Write(string value) is called on each of them exactly once. It will fail if Write is not called or is called more than once on any of the strings.

**Update**

Generally mocked methods must be virtual and depending on your mocking framework, the mock's method may need to be setup before being called so it may not be a valid test at all since StreamWriter is a concrete class and Write is not a virtual method.

Answer (score 0):

Given the mocked `StreamWriter`

At best the `foreach` loop being used to verify with the mock that the each string in the expected lines array was called on the mocked stream writer's `Write` method exactly once during the exercising of the subject under test.

The test will fail if any of the expected lines are written more than once.

Review [Moq: Quickstart - Verification](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart#verification)

Take the following class as an example of a possible subject that depends on a `StreamWriter`

```
public class SubjectUnderTest {
    private StringWriter stringWriter;

    public SubjectUnderTest(StringWriter stringWriter) {
        this.stringWriter = stringWriter;
    }

    public void WriteLines(string[] lines) {
        foreach (var line in lines) {
            this.stringWriter.Write(line);
        }
    }
}
```

The dependency would be mocked when testing and the functionality of the method under test can be verified in isolation.

For example.

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1() {
    //Arrange
    var _streamWriterMock = new Mock<StringWriter>();
    string[] expectedLines = new[] { "line1", "line2" };
    var subject = new SubjectUnderTest(_streamWriterMock.Object);

    //Act
    subject.WriteLines(expectedLines);

    //Assert
    foreach (var line in expectedLines) {
        _streamWriterMock.Verify(a => a.Write(line), Times.Exactly(1));
    }
}
```

If however, `expectedLines` had duplicates like `{ "lineN", "lineN" }` Then the above test would fail as the verification is expecting the `Write` method to be called exactly one time with a given string value.